# Leaflet show multiple markers and setView

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have sample code that uses `Leaflet` and `open street map`. Nevertheless, i am not sure how could i add more `markers`. Besides i don't really understand the sense of `setView` function i read that it's for `centering map`, but what is the sense to have it since there is only one `marker` which should be automaticly as `map` center point, and from the other hand if there will be more markers what is a sense of setView?

**Additional question:** Is Leaflet and open street map free for commercial use?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mapDiv" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
<script>
    // position we will use later
    var lat = 40.73;
    var lon = -74.00;

    // initialize map
    map = L.map('mapDiv').setView([lat, lon], 13);

    // set map tiles source
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);

    // add marker to the map
    marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);

    // add popup to the marker
    marker.bindPopup("<b>ACME CO.</b><br />This st. 48<br />New York").openPopup();

</script>
</body>

</html>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

> there is only one marker which should be automaticly as map center point

There is nothing in Leaflet itself that would automatically center a map view on your only Marker.

On the other hand, the sample code you show does achieve this, using `setView` on the same coordinates as your only Marker.

> if there will be more markers what is a sense of setView?

`setView` gives you the ability to define which part of the map you want to initially display in your viewport, independently from your map content / layers (in your case: your markers). Obviously you can define a view that shows all your Markers at once as well.

> i am not sure how could i add more markers.

Do `L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);` as many times as needed, with `lat` and `lon` different each time as needed.

> Is Leaflet and open street map free for commercial use?

Leaflet is distributed under a [BSD 2-clause license](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/LICENSE), commercial use is permitted.

OpenStreetMap **data** is free, but **not the tiles** generated by OSM servers. There are many services generating similar tiles from OSM data or other sources that you can check out. E.g. you can search for "leaflet providers".

Comment: I dont fully understand. What tile provider i use in my code? Which tile provider is free to use for commercial usage for instance and what part of my code should i change regarding that tiles?

Comment: The Leaflet tutorials and "leaflet-providers" plugin should help clarify your understanding.

Comment: can you give example or redirect me to correct place? Was searching but havent found

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapDiv" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
<script>
    // position we will use later
    var lat = 40.73;
    var lon = -74.00;

    // initialize map
    map = L.map('mapDiv');

    // set map tiles source
  
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
  
  /*
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt?lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 13,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map);
*/
  
  map.locate({setView: false, maxZoom: 8});
    
  // add marker to the map
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lon), 18); 
    marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);

    // add popup to the marker
    marker.bindPopup("<b>ACME CO.</b><br />This st. 48<br />New York").openPopup();

</script>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

[Map Tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).